# BeautifulSoup error when loading the parser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So BS4 was working earlier today however it has problems when trying to load a page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

name = input("")

twitter = requests.get("https://twitter.com/" + name)
#instagram = requests.get("https//instagram.com/" + name)
#website = requests.get("https://" + name + ".com")

twitter_soup = BeautifulSoup(twitter, 'html.parser')
twitter_available = twitter_soup.body.findAll(text="This account doesn't exist")
if twitter_available == True:
    print("Available")
else:
    print("Not Available")
```

So the line where twitter_soup is declared I get the following errors

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Programming\Python\name-checker.py", line 12, in 
> twitter_soup = BeautifulSoup(twitter, 'html.parser')
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4_*init*_.py", line 310, in **init**
> elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
> TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

I have also tried the other parsers the docs were suggesting however none are working.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out.
So I had to use the actual html which is twitter.text in this situation instead of just using the request.